# Translate incoming USB signals to keystrokes/macros

Tags: c++, macros, usb, signals, voip

I am looking for a piece of software, or assistance with where to start for coding, that will let you select a USB device and convert its output signals (when buttons are pressed on the device) into keystrokes or configurable macros.

In more detail, I have this remote control (more accurately, a USB handset/phone) that sends USB signals depending on which button is pressed and the software I currently use converts those signals into keystrokes or macros. The software I currently use however is extremely limited, non-configurable and obsolete. The software which I retrieved from the CD that the device came in is simply named 'USBPhone 5 in 1' however there is no mention of this anywhere on the internet.

The device is unfortunately unbranded and also has very little visibility on the internet so I cannot see if there's any updated software or even any way to edit it.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: "Looking for software"  would be off-topic, and "where to start coding" would be `int main()`.

Comment: General answer: I think the question is «how to build a driver», which would be a big lost a time in the case of a keyboard. If you want to analyse packets and signals, you need a CAN/BUS analyser and a packet reader like wireshark. This said, to go deeper, you got to know that older PS2 keyboards are much more easier to analyse, as their output is analogik. It mean that you can analyse signals with a regular oscilloscope. 
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/298592/how-to-measure-voltage-in-a-ps-2-keyboard-cable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to start by getting basic understanding of the USB standard and device classes. Then you need to find out if your device implements a specific device class or some proprietary interfaces. Then you will either need to use a driver for the device class or implement a proprietary driver.

While USB is abbreviation from Universal Serial Bus, it is not transferring some random analogue data but well defined digital packets. The standard defines Audio Class for audio devices, Video class for video devices etc. Most devices implement one or more of those classes. For keyboards and mouse it defines HID class, which is most likely what your device implements. You can find HID device class related specifications [here](http://www.usb.org/developers/docs/docs/hidpage/). It is not the most simple one to begin with, but it should work when you just plug the device to your PC and open e.g. notepad and start writing. USB device class codes are listed [here](http://www.usb.org/developers/defined_class).

In order to find out what device class your device implements, you need to read it's descriptors. In Windows one of the easier ways is to use [usbview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff560019(v=vs.85).aspx). You can read more about USB decriptors from [here](http://www.beyondlogic.org/usbnutshell/usb5.shtml).

You do not mention what is your USB host (Windows or Linux PC, Mac or something else), so I am not going to go into actual USB driver implementation, but hopefully I was able to give you some information on what could be needed. In any case, if the device has some proprietary implementation, you will either need to have specification for it, or reverse engineer it by monitoring the USB packets. There are lots of expensive hardware solutions on the market for analyzing the USB traffic, but there are also some free SW solutions that might be good enough for your purpose. Quick Googling brought up [this](https://freeusbanalyzer.com/).

Comment: Thanks a lot for this really useful information! I understand everything you have said and I will work from your much provided resources to proceed with my requirements. For the record the host is Windows. Thanks a ton for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can try joyToKey, this software do exactly what you want but with gamedpad. I don't know if it will work well with your USB controller.

http://joytokey.net/en/

Comment: Unfortunately the device doesn't register as a game controller, therefore this software is of no use to me. Thanks a lot anyway!